# How to read a .p archive whit pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I have a '.p' archive and I never used this kind of extension in pandas, I tried to read this archive with the 'read_csv' function but I get an error.

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

taxi_owners = pd.read_csv('taxi_owners.p', encoding='utf-8')
```

But this doesn't work, and the result was:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is .p archive?  Documentation?

Comment: Isn't it a pickle file? https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's a pickle file. Try following:

```
data = pd.read_pickle('taxi_owners.p')
```